# Export a repository from gitlab.com

Tags: import, export, gitlab

There are similar questions out there on how to export a gitlab repository from server A to server B, keeping issues, milestones, etc. My problem is that the repo is hosted at gitlab.com and I don't have acces to it's database, etc. I've searched for an "export" button in the Gitlab UI but I don't find it. I've also searched in Google.

Is it possible to export a repository from gitlab.com (with issues, milestones,...) and import it in my own server?

Comment: Import from might work: http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/importing/import_projects_from_gitlab_com.html But it only claims to do the repos and issues. So your milestones and other things might get left behind.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try as soon as possible to report feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As twk3 suggests, the import currently only handles issues and the code repository. There are various feature requests right now for adding merge requests, wikis, etc.

Merge requests - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2833
Wiki - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2834